# Which "Rockwell van" ran incredibly rough for the first two minutes? (call to the radio program Car Talk)

Tags: history, identify-this-object, space-art

A caller to the long-running NPR radio talk show [Car Talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_Talk) described a problem with their Rockwell van. While it started fine, it ran "incredibly rough" for the first two minutes.

Is it possible to identify the "van" and it's driver, the other vehicle, and the date and any other identifying features (e.g. mission number) when this call-in took place?

Listen to episode #2137 ("Thirty Four Years of the North American Wacko") starting at about `18:00` at [1](https://www.npr.org/2021/09/10/1036087880/-2137-thirty-four-years-of-the-north-american-wacko), [2](https://www.cartalk.com/radio/show/2137-thirty-four-years-north-american-whacko))

Comment: It was a shuttle mission, not Apollo. I remember listening to Car Talk at the time, but long enough ago that details are missing.

Comment: He literally says he’s on Space Shuttle Atlantis and confirms he is John Grunsfeld.

Comment: Supporting closure for both reasons (i) missing source and (ii) problematically irrelevant basis including 'van' and 'other vehicle'.

Comment: @terry-s the sources are there, I'll flag the misleading comment to have it removed. The YouTube link was audio-only. Since I'd included two more links to the same audio, it was a *triply redundant link*. As mentioned in the first sentence, it's a *radio program.* The "Rockwell van" is what Mission Specialist 2 [John Grunsfeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_M._Grunsfeld) called Space Shuttle Atlantis. I put it in quotes in the title for you, but if you don't  like the term then your argument is with him, not my quoting him.

Comment: @uhoh  thanks for reply. my comment & vote wd become needless (and I'd try to remove them) if the question were changed just enough to make clear the relevant connection to the subject of this forum, and a way to access the source.

Comment: @terry-s Hmm... along with the reduced-gravity-sports and reduced-gravity cooking tags, I suppose I could create a reduced-gravity-humor tag, but I don't think that would reach orbit. We do have a small but well-received body of space-anecdote questions (e.g. peeing on tires of buses, saying "let's light this candle") but I don't think we need a tag for that. In the end, people just decide what is and isn't on-topic as we go along. As for "the subject of this forum", Stack Exchange is not a forum, and the sum total of what is consider on-topic in an SE site is not a singular, individual topic.

Comment: @terry-s Since humor can be considered an art form, I'll add the space-art tag, and since this episode first aired in January 1997 over 25 years ago, I'll also add the history tag. Usually identify-this-object questions include an image of an object, but there's nothing wrong with presenting Grunsfeld's audio reference *which was being broadcast from space via TDRS satellite link(!)* as the specimen requiring identification, so I'll keep that tag in place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to identify the "van" and it's driver, the other vehicle, and the date and any other identifying features (e.g. mission number) when this call-in took place?

The vehicle described is the [Space Shuttle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle) [*Atlantis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Atlantis).

- "Rockwell van" - the shuttle orbiter's prime contractor was Rockwell International. Like a van, the shuttle has a crew cabin up front and a big empty cargo area behind, with a pair of large doors to provide access.
- "Runs incredibly rough for about two minutes" -- the shuttle solid rocket boosters burn for 124 seconds.
- "There's kind of a jolt, and then it runs smooth, but only for about six and a half more minutes, then at that point the engine dies." -- the main engines run for a total of eight and a half minutes before main engine cutoff. The boosters, being solid rockets producing five times the thrust of the mains, are a much rougher ride.
- "Two different vehicles by serial number, and both of them exactly the same thing." -- this rules out John Young! Both of his shuttle missions were on *Columbia*.
- "When we use the brakes, they glow red-hot" -- As Jacob Krall points out in a comment, this may be a reference to the shuttle's thermal protection system, which gets very hot as the shuttle's speed is bled off during reentry. It could also refer to the actual wheel brakes, which get extremely hot during landing -- I couldn't find a definitive figure, but one early shuttle development document suggested they could get into the ballpark of 1200º F (650º C).

At this point, I confess I cheated and looked it up. The astronaut calling in was [John Grunsfeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_M._Grunsfeld), during his second shuttle flight, [STS-81 aboard *Atlantis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-81) in 1997. He had previously flown [STS-67 on *Endeavour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-67).

Comment: The brakes glowing red-hot is surely a reference to the [thermal protection system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_thermal_protection_system), not the wheels.

Answer (score 2):

Per [Gizmodo's story on this](https://gizmodo.com/the-time-an-astronaut-called-into-car-talk-from-the-spa-5924311) (nothing special about the content, just clicked the first link on Google for "car talk space shuttle"):

> This was John Grunsfeld, who was, at the time, aboard the Space Shuttle Atlantis on a STS-81, a mission to Mir.